# How do I create a log of robocopy actions and save in a text file named with today's date?

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I am copying some assets from one folder to another using robocopy in command prompt. However, I want to log name of all those copied assets in a .txt file. This .txt file should be saved in the form of "currentDate.txt".

Actual Scenario: We are going to run a scheduler once daily. This scheduler will copy all the assets from one folder to another.

Refer below link for a screenshot of Robocopy Command:

[image: Robocopy]

Any help will be highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### I want to log name of all those copied assets in a .txt file.

> This .txt file should be saved in the form of "currentDate.txt".

- Use the robocopy `/log:<LogFile>` option.
- You might also want to use the `/tee` option

  Writes the status output to the console window, as well as to the log file.

Example batch file (`copyassets.cmd`):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
  set _date=%%a%%b%%c
  )
echo robocopy ship shore /log:%_date%.txt
```

- Modify as you like to get your prefered date format.
- Remove the last `echo` if you are happy with the date format
- Use `/s` if your source directory contains subdirectories that need copying.

---

#### Syntax

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]
```

...

**Logging options**

...

[image]

Source [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)

Comment: After a long discussion we were able to get a command working .... but what happens with this command is that it overwrites the previous log. I want it to create a new log life (.txt) the next day (each day will have a new log file in the name of current date)

Comment: Can you please check this link http://superuser.com/questions/1104796/robocopy-error-5-0x00000005-accessing-source-directory-server-parentfolder and let me know if you have an answer for this ?

Comment: No. Pinging users to answer unrelated questions is not acceptable behaviour. Please don't do that.

Comment: Ok. Sure. I thought you might have an answer for this. But that's alright.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution to create a different log file every day. You can just call robocopy in PowerShell or batch command file and do your file manipulation and have it create the log, then rename the log file on the next line. The example:

```
Rename-Item -Path "C:\logs\robocopy.log" -NewName "robocopy-$(Get-Date -F yyyy.MM.dd)$($_.Extension).log"
```

The result will be a dated file like this:

`robocopy-2021.06.22.log`

Answer (score 0):

The log of RoboCopy is in DOS format which isn't really good.. Try GS RichCopy - has got all the features of RoboCopy, but it has some more features like copying open/locked files, can copy the timestamps, and has a GUI interface with a nice looking log which you can easily copy and paste in a notepad.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does not answer the original question."How do I create a log of robocopy actions and save in a text file named with today's date? ” under Event Trace Sessions after the Anniversary Update?" the OP stated "using robocopy in command prompt." software advice is generally best with more information and links but not so much that it looks like an add. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
rem formating-date
set shortTime=%time:~0,8%
set shortTime=%shortTime: =0%
set YY=%date:~6,4%
set MM=%date:~3,2%
set /A DD=%date:~0,2%
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining why this works.  Otherwise, the bot may delete your answer.